# loading from app.yaml as a wsgi application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

I couldn't immediately determine if this was possible by reading the source of the sdk.

But, is there a way to get a wsgi version of the application that dev_appserver would load from app.yaml?

I was so hoping there would be a function like

```
def app_from_yaml(path_to_yaml):
    ...
```

If this existed I could actually write automated tests for the blobstore logic and not have to do the crap manually anymore. Any Ideas?

Comment: I went ahead and put a feature request in for this. After getting similar answers through the premium support channel. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7266

Comment: I also want to test my web2py GAE app on webtest. The good way for this requires the mechanism described in your question. The only other useful relevant info I could find on the net is WSGIProxy: http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/proxying-tests.html

Comment: yeah I have done it with wsgiproxy too, the problem is then you are incurring the http overhead, and it can be really slow. For the app at my day job that's the difference between 3 minutes and 45 to run the test suite.

Comment: FWIW, I did manage to get an equivalent applcation.ini running for tests using Paste urlmap. But I had to write a blobstore handler mock and a bit of middleware to do some route trickery. This is hardly ideal since I have to manually keep it in sync with the app.yaml but I am able to test everything outside of http now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any solution that does what you want. I strongly suspect the reason is that dev_appserver does a lot of things when loading an application, including parsing the various yaml files, set up routing, stub out APIs (both, App Engine and Python), restrict the environment to emulate appserver, and so on. A function app_from_yaml(path_to_yaml) would have to do what dev_appserver.py does. And since dev_appserver.py does it already, I think no-one bothered to add another implementation.

I see 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. Make the blobstore API more testable
2. start your app with dev_appserver and run tests against it

The former one is rather difficult because it would require to refactor how things are done currently which risks the introduction of subtle regressions. The latter is something we do a lot for such large tests (which are really integration tests). We use gaedriver for that.

In your specific case where you want to test blobstore (which we do, too), we start an app from within a test, upload a blob using a certain URL and then hit another and check if the blob was processed correctly. It's not as nice as using testbed, but it works, is fairly straight-forward and fairly fast.

Comment: schuppe, thanks for the thoughts, I agree that dev_appserver does more than just bring up a bunch of request handlers. It still seems like it's not that much of a stretch to think the HTTP headers and body could come in through a wsgi callable after all the machinery is setup.

I had no idea that gaedriver existed, I had written something similar a while back. So I will have to check this out. 

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but the answer may lie in `google.appengine.ext.webapp.util.run_wsgi_app`.

In terms of the blobstore itself, there is already `google.appengine.api.blobstore.blobstore_stub` which can be used to test against the Blobstore (though I don't really understand what "manually" means in your context, so maybe that's not helpful).

Comment: the run_wsgi_app is the reverse of what i'm asking. and the blobstore_stub is part of the equation but as far as I know it does not allow you to control the url for the uploads and how it's generated , so as it stands if get a url that says http://testbed.example.com/_ah/........" which goes nowhere when you are running your app as wsgi under webtest. the only way I can think of to make the app engine magic urls available is to either run devappserver or get a wsgi app from the app.yaml.